# Calling OpenXML objects in c++ project

Tags: automation, c++-cli, openxml

How to call DocumentFormat and other relevant objects in C++/CLi with OpenXML as added reference into the program. I couldnot find any documentation on how to call these objects. "Using DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Package" gives error in c++ project such as follows:
"
1>clitest.cpp(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
1>clitest.cpp(7): error C2873: 'DocumentFormat' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
1>clitest.cpp(7): error C2059: syntax error : '.'
"
However I have added DocumentFormat, as reference to my project.

Regards
YogiK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ namespace syntax uses :: as a delimiter.  This code compiles::

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging; 

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    WordprocessingDocument^ doc = WordprocessingDocument::Create("C:\\mydoc.xdoc",DocumentFormat::OpenXml::WordprocessingDocumentType::Document);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked. Strange that it is not mentioned on the relevant tutorials that I came across.